# Grails 3 : SessionFactory Bean is not injecting in Service

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to bulk add data from a file, i read a method from this portal to bulk add the data using batch processing

http://krixisolutions.com/bulk-insert-grails-gorm/

When i used this technique and changed my app according to it my code is not working, i've been working for days to find method to bulk save the data to make the process faster, by simple manual flush it takes 4 minutes to save 1000 lines of data in database, i want to make this time as little as possible

In the below given code whenever i debug the code it does stop after SessionFactory, i dont understand what the problem is, as i am very new to grails and dont have any experience with sessionFactory or transactions.

Here is my code:

```
   runAsync {
            res = benchmark { result ->
                    Session session = SessionFactory.openSession()
Transaction tx = (Transaction)session.beginTransaction()




                    groovyFile.eachLine {


                        String[] tagData = it.split(',')

                        def isTimeToLive = true


                        if (isTimeToLive) {
                            try {
                                caller = new Caller(callingNumber: 
                       tagData.getAt(0), callerName: tagData.getAt(1))
                                session.save(caller)
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                log.error(ex.getMessage())
                            }

                            caller.validate()
                            if (caller.hasErrors()) {
                                println("message", "Invalid calling number. Digits can only be from 10 to 15.")
                            }

                            callCallerList = new CallCallerList(caller: caller, callerList: callerList)
                            callCallerList.validate()
                            if (callCallerList.hasErrors()) {
                                println("message", "Invalid calling number. Digits can only be from 10 to 15.")
                            } else {
                                session.save(callCallerList)
                            }

                        }
                        count++;
                        if (count % 100 == 0) {
                            session?.flush()
                            session?.clear()
                        }
                    }
                    tx.commit();
                    session.close();

                }


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails you can simply use `withSession{}` or `withTransaction{}`:

I would write like that:

```
Caller.withTransaction{
  int count = 0
  groovyFile.splitEachLine( ',' ){ String[] line ->
    Caller caller = new Caller( callingNumber:line[ 0 ], callerName:line[ 1 ] )
    if( !caller.save( flush:0 == count % 100 ) ) println caller.errors
    count++
  }
}
```

You should not really handle the session by hand.

UPDATE

> Why transaction do a rapid insertion while sessions fail?

No. Usually, a transaction wraps a session automatically, so `withSession{}` works as fast as `withTransaction{}`.

> Is it because session was not cleaning the cache properly or because each sql query was doing its own flush?

Yes, session's cache is not cleaned-up unless you `flush` it or `close` it. This is what is done in my code or in any recommendation about bulk processing in GORM or Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks alot, this solution solved my problem. It improved the insertion time for 1000 records from 4 minutes to 10-15 sec. This is massive improvement, but i have 1 question. Why transaction do a rapid insertion while sessions fail. Is it because session was not cleaning the cache properly or because each sql query was doing its own flush. I am little bit confused still, and please explain how transactions handled it?

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, before this i used "withNewSession" but when i made same conditions of "session.flush" and "session.clear" it didnt work at all inside closure, i checked through different conditions but "withNewSession" didnt flush the data even on right conditions, is there something i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`openSession` is not a static method, you should be injecting `sessionFactory` and opening a session if you don't already have one.

```
class SomeService {
  def sessionFactory
  void someMethod() {
    def session = sessionFactory.openSession() //or sessionFactory.currentSession, not sure how this works with async operations
    //all your stuff
    if(<threshold>) { 
       session.flush()
       session.clear() //helps performance on exceptionally large imports, probably not so much on ~1000 records
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it after injecting sessionFactory in my service by using "def sessionFactory" but it gives an exception that there is no hibernate session related to this thread. can you please explain this thing?

Comment: Unfortunately, without a fuller understanding of your code stack, I don't know why you don't have a hibernate session at this point.  The above solution to use `withTransaction()` or `withNewTransaction()` seem to be better for your scenario.  If you still need access to the session inside your block (e.g., for processing a million rows rather than a thousand), you can get it from inside the closure.